# Filter based on two tables Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models with a through table:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    first = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Newsletter(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Tiffany's Dynamic Digest")
    body = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField('Subscriber', through='NewsletterEngagement')

class NewsletterEngagement(models.Model):
    subscriber = models.ForeignKey(Subscriber, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    newsletter = models.ForeignKey(Newsletter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I need to search for: All subscribers where email_confirmed=True AND who have not received a newsletter.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you try and where did you fail https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Thanks Iklinac, i've spent most of the morning trying to understand ManyToMany databases and this problem has me stumped. I've read the Django documentation, but I just need someone top point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

After reading Ivaylo Donhev's excellent article:

https://www.hacksoft.io/blog/django-filter-chaining

I came up with this solution:

```
Subscriber.objects.filter(email_confirmed=True).filter(newsletter__id__isnull=True).distinct()
```

I would appreciate suggestions on how I can improve it.